# Runtime components missing and known corrections not working

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I've been working on a JavaFX project for a while and I try to launch it outside of the IDE with the jar made.

My pom.xml file is as follows:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>software</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>Charachter_Creator</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>charm-glisten</id>
      <name>charm-glisten Repository</name>
      <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aerofx</groupId>
      <artifactId>aerofx</artifactId>
      <version>0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jfxcore</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>15-ea+1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
      <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
      <version>11.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
      <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.simtechdata</groupId>
      <artifactId>Switcher</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.misc</groupId>
      <artifactId>miscellaneousWidgets</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>Menu.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>8</source>
            <target>8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>dependency/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>Menu.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
  
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/ressources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>fxml/*.fxml</include>
                <include>images/*.png</include>
                <include>images/*.jpg</include>
                <include>CSS/*.css</include>
                <include>pdfs/*.pdf</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>

</project>
```

To launch my jar, I type:

```
java -jar software-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar --module-path /home/lambevin/Downloads/javafx-sdk-17/lib/ --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx-swt,javafx.web
```

I've tried with `=`, with `""`, with only `javafx.controls` and `javafx.fxml` but nothing works.

To be clear, the original message error keeps showing: `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`

The path given to `--module-path` is the one to a directory extracted from a zip downloaded separately.

Adding `--module-path` and `--add-modules` is the only solution I've found on the internet. Does anyone have a clue about my issue?

EDIT: Minimal reproducible example
Base code from the javafx-archetype-fxml for Maven given by the VSCode command `Java: Create Java Project...`

```
package demo;
 
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
 
public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
 
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>demo</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>demo</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>demo.HelloWorld</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>dependency/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>demo.HelloWorld</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: “Nothing works” -> what does it do? Is there a stack trace?  Is there minimum code that generated the error? Can you put that in the question? Read [mcve]

Comment: I've done my best to be more clear. Don't hesitate to tell me again if something seems vague

Comment: You don’t need to create a jar with dependencies that includes JavaFX packages using an assembly.  When you run the app you are providing the arguments to put JavaFX on the module path from a lib directory.  That should be all you need.

Comment: Also if you use a assembly to create a jar with dependencies that include JavaFX classes, then I think that will run JavaFX off the class path which is not a supported configuration, Classes in the JavaFX modules only should be on the module path.  Also you only need the JavaFX modules you actually use, you don’t need things like javafx.swing if you aren’t using it.

Comment: You are’s using swt, so you shouldn’t reference, even if you were, I don’t think the module name you used of javafx-swt looks right. I assume an invalid module reference would just be ignored but it could cause an error (I don’t know I haven’t tried it).  Anyway it shouldn’t be referenced as you don’t need it.

Comment: I think JavaFX 17 Maven modules are currently broken, so I suggest you use JavaFX 16 unless you know the Maven modules for 17 have.been fixed.

Comment: As an alternative to the assembly you might want to investigate the jlink and jpackage tools.

Comment: Your groupid should not be org.openjfx, that is not your group.

Comment: Okay, that's a lot of things, sorry about what seems to be obvious for you I'm still learning

I'll look into it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of issues which at least look strange and error prone and that's probably not all of it yet.

javafx-fxml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jfxcore</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
  <version>15-ea+1</version>
</dependency>
```

Shouldn't that be

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
  <version>17</version>
</dependency>
```

It has a wrong group ID and inconsistent version. Never mix versions!

You are building for Java 8 but you are pulling in things which have a minimum version of 11.

Please fix your project setup before you continue and then follow the official documentation: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: I agree with you (and will modify it) but as you can see in my minimal reproducible example, this is not the cause of my problem...
I don't see where you can tell I'm building for Java8, my `java --version` command tells me I work with openjdk 16.0.2

Comment: <maven.compiler.source>1.8 and <configuration><source>8</source<target>8</target></configuration> in your original pom.